# Not able to route using after_inactive_sign_up_path_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

I overridden RegistrationController my_devise/Registration controller
i overridden the following methos:

def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   awaiting_confirmation_path

end

I also have a new method in my RegistrationController named:
def awaiting_confirmation(resource)
 do tuff....
end

My routing file looks likethis:

devise_for :accounts, :controllers => {
                          :registrations  => "my_devise/registrations"}

resources :registration do
    match "awaiting_confirmation"    => "registrations#awaiting_confirmation"
  end

I get an error message:
No route matches {:action=>"awaiting_confirmation", :controller=>"registrations"}

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

resources :registration do
  match "awaiting_confirmation" => "registrations#awaiting_confirmation"
end

Where are you specifying that your registrations controller is in my_devise folder??
You need to specify that manually, because Rails follows conventions, and therefore its looking in the app/controllers directory to find the registrations controller, that you have written yourself.
To get more idea about this, have a look at the output of `rake routes` command and find the route that rails has generated for it.

Comment: i have this line in the router:
devise_for :accounts, :controllers => { :registrations => "my_devise/registrations"}

Comment: problem fixed. I used match "awaiting_confirmation"    => "my_devide/registrations#awaiting_confirmation"
I used rake route to trouble shoot the problem