# rails devise issues- sign in redirect not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

some issues I have about rails4 devise:

Sign in redirect not working

I have these overrides in

```
RegistrationsController

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      signininfo_docs_path
    end


    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      signupinfo_docs_path
    end

    def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      signupinfo_docs_path
    end
```

and routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,:confirmable
end
```

Issue 1: 
 Only `after_sign_up_path_for` works, `after_sign_in_path_for` and `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` not working at all

Issue 2:

I copied confirmation_token from my database trying to confirm a user by this link

localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=9e29d1fc0a91300815ed101073c08843c47673e7b6528d8bd4639ed4801dsds

It always complains `Confirmation token is invalid`

Thanks for any help/hints.

Answer (score 0):

`RegistrationsController` is not the correct place to put this code. The appropriate place to put this is in your `ApplicationController`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      signininfo_docs_path
    end


    def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      signupinfo_docs_path
    end

    def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      signupinfo_docs_path
    end    
end
```

Also, for issue #2, if you are upgrading from devise on Rails 3.x, you need to change the `views/devise/mailers/confirmation_mailer.html.erb`.

Instead of `@resource.confirmation_token`, it should just be using `@token`

For the `inactive_signup_for` method, I refer you to this question
[Not able to route using after_inactive_sign_up_path_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633011/not-able-to-route-using-after-inactive-sign-up-path-for)

Comment: Thanks `after_sign_in_path_for` works after I moved these codes to ApplicationController. But`after_inactive_sign_up_path_for`  still not working. I think a not confirmed user signing in should trigger this method . is that right?